# How to choose a winforms deployment solution

Tags: winforms, deployment, clickonce, sql-server-ce

I am looking for a winforms deployment solution which respect the following constraints :

1. The application must be shared for all windows users on the machine
2. The database (Sql Server Compact 3.5 SP1) must be shared for all the users
3. I have to keep database data on update
4. I have to check and launch the update programmatically

My first idea was to choose ClickOnce but the tool doesn't support multi-user per machine install. MSI installer supports this constraint.

Is there a way to combine both or another solution?

Answer (score 0):

MSI packages are indeed the solution. Although ClickOnce has a built-in update mechanism, most MSI setup authoring tools offer updater applications. Also, during an MSI-based install you can handle the original files any way you want.

You can find a list of setup authoring tools here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

Commercial tools are easier to use, but require a license. Free tools are more complicated, but they are free.